# Android OpenGL ES Bump Mapping

Tags: android, opengl-es

So, I have scoured the net, looking for information on how one would do this. And so far, all I've come up with is....nohting.

Any one got a better starting point than http://www.paulsprojects.net/tutorials/simplebump/simplebump.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting OpenGL 2.0 is in fact quite easy and you just need a normal map, and a shader that handles the lighting equation per pixel. I found this for you: http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-four-introducing-basic-texturing/

Comment: We are targeting 2.0. I'll take a look, but from first glance, this looks exactly what we need.

Comment: I'm glad it could be useful.

Comment: If you end using this tutorial please mark the question as answered, thanks.

Comment: This answer one question, and made me ask others. Right now I'm working on getting a simple heightmap working.